Do I need to defeat the Maguu Kenki to get the Fort Mumei Warding Stone?
This guide and the Wiki don't say that defeating the Maguu Kenki Marionette boss nearby is required for the Warding Stone, but the guide maker defeated the boss and I haven't?
The Elemental Traces are pointing to the right spot, with two traces but no Warding Stone, and undefeated Marionette.
